# BAckground Anova vs Individual Protein ANOVA

Tags: anova

In proteomics often two conditions are compared (let's say control vs treatment) and the abundance of thousands of proteins (let's say 20.000) is measured.

To determine which proteins are significantly changed by the treatment the abundance ratio  Treatment/Control is calculated.

Now, in the proteomics field, is common to see different approaches to calculate statistical significance for these ratios (So, what proteins are affected by the treatment).

-Background ANOVA. Every ratio is compared to the rest of the protein' ratios, and the ANOVA test is calculated. If the p-value (or adjusted) is <0.05, then is considered that treatment had an effect on the protein.
-Individual protein ANOVA. Here the experiment needs 5 replicates (unusual to have >5 replicates, since each experiment is expensive). Then for each protein, the 5 controls are compared to the 5 treated by the ANOVA test. Here, the rest of the proteins do not play a role, just the replicates.

I found the two methods to have weaknesses.  The 'background ANOVA' do not consider replicates. Some people use n=1. If n>1 how should significance be calculated?

For 'individual proteins ANOVA', the information of each set is lost (each control is paired to each treatment: C1/T1; C2/T2, ...) This information is also lost. Is it possible to run an ANOVA test here, without losing the information of the pairs?